Addressing the Impact of Unknown Authorship on PhD. Students’ Academic Reputation and Remedies
As a current PhD. student, I have observed some troubling practices. It is not uncommon for advisors to add students’ names as co-authors on papers resulting from collaborations with other research groups, often without the students’ prior knowledge. Students typically discover their authorship only through notification emails, frequently after publication, and have often never seen the paper before. This situation is both frustrating and disempowering, especially since these papers are usually unrelated to the students' PhD. dissertations. I am concerned about how such involuntary authorship might affect students’ academic reputations. Could this impact their PhD. degree? What measures can prevent such issues, and what steps can students take to address and mitigate the repercussions of these ‘forced authorship’ after publication
Additional info
Some advisors take pride in these practices because having their students' names appear in numerous publications can, to some extent, enhance the students' academic visibility. Advisors may assign authorship based on their preferences, often listing names of students they favor—those they deem promising—in many collaborative papers with other research groups, while other students may not receive such recognition.
Typically, students whose names appear on these papers might have contributed by sending samples or have specific experience related to certain experiments or simulations detailed in the paper. It is indeed perplexing that authorship can be assigned for minimal or indirect contributions, or even for work that is only tangentially related.
Students are aware that these practices are unethical. They have privately confided their concerns to me, and I fully empathize with their distress. They often have no knowledge of how these decisions are made, and by the time they discover their names appear in a publication, the journal has already received the submission.
Directly questioning their advisor is not feasible because the issue has already occurred. After publication, raising concerns becomes even more difficult. Publicizing the issue could result in the retraction of the paper, which would be a severe setback for both the advisor and the students, potentially jeopardizing the students' research careers. Sometimes, after publication, if the advisor remembers, they might provide a brief explanation to the students; if the advisor forgets, no clarification is given.
Consequently, many students remain silent, with no evidence beyond the journal's email to demonstrate their lack of involvement.
Thank you for all the feedback.
I would like to provide some further clarification. While the practice of advisors adding students' names to publications without their involvement is not widespread, it remains a “tradition” in certain research groups.
Our field is centered on the design of electronic devices, with a particular focus on sensor design. In this context, advisors often engage in extensive collaborations with other research groups, leading to the publication of joint papers. However, the students under these advisors frequently have no direct involvement in these collaborative projects, even if their research areas are somewhat related. For example, consider a collaboration on the design of a temperature sensor. A student with substantial expertise in thermal simulations—similar to those required in the project—may have their name added to the publication, despite the fact that their simulations involve entirely different parameters. The student may only become aware of this when they receive a notification from the journal after the paper has been submitted. This is just one possible scenario. Typically, the student’s name appears far down the list of authors, usually beyond the fifth author. The justification for including the student’s name merely due to a general research area overlap is, at best, questionable.
I am seeking guidance on whether there are any institutional mechanisms that could prevent such situations. Additionally, what steps can students take to protect themselves from potential accusations of academic misconduct? Naturally, contacting the editor to request a retraction seems too extreme. Furthermore, considering that these papers are usually unrelated to the student's dissertation work, could these practices have any impact on the dissertation?

In what country/countries are you seeing this? Are the papers being published in reputable journals?

Did the student's contribute and what fields? For example, labor intense projects from the lab- or field-based projects might include the student making a meaningful contribution even without helping write. However, it is generally considered unethical to submit a paper without letting all coauthors read the manuscript.

To my knowledge, this issue is prevalent among research groups in many East Asian countries, although these journals are typically lesser-known and of lower profile.

@user_ababa_gwzddx can you edit those details into your answer? Also, welcome to the site. I would encourage you to take the tour.

@Richard Erickson  It is not as labor-intensive as fields like biology, nor does it depend heavily on individual expertise as in mathematics or physics. Instead, it pertains to areas such as sensor design and flexible electronics. Typically, students' research areas have some relevance to the papers they are 'forced to be listed as authors' on, even though they did not directly contribute to the work. The rationale of attributing authorship based on the relevance of research topics is quite puzzling.

@Richard Erickson  Thank you very much for your prompt reply！

@Richard Erickson  This issue also reflects certain flaws in the submission process. Some journals require all authors to provide signatures upon submission, confirming that they have reviewed the manuscript and are aware of their authorship. However, many journals rely solely on the corresponding author’s assurance that all authors have consented to the publication, which creates a loophole. It is this loophole that enables advisors to arbitrarily assign authorship to students.

Unwilling is different from unknowing, and usually worse. You describe unknowing authorship here.

@JonCuster  To be precise, the situation is as follows: before submission, the student is unaware; after submission, even if unwilling, the student must reluctantly accept the reality.

Most journals send a confirmation email at submission where those who object can contact the editor, failure to do so means they agree with the submission. Stating that the student must reluctantly accept is also nonsense. You mention "disempowering" in your comment. All authors have the power to disapprove of a publication throughout the process, however, with that a situation can become awkward, uncomfortable, and have consequences. That does not make you disempowered, but it does mean you face a difficult situation.

@R1NaNo The reality is that advisors have relatively significant "authority" over students and can, to some extent, decide whether students will successfully obtain their degrees. Although students technically have the right to contact editors, doing so can create an awkward situation. Consequently, students are, to some degree, "forced" to accept authorship. They also recognize that their contributions may not justify being listed as authors, which makes them feel very guilty.

I’m only used to the opposite effect (high level advisors on as "authors" without contributing) but it’s generally not a problem for an individual because "everyone does it" and people have more to lose than to gain by calling it out. What makes you concerned that there will be a (negative) impact for the students? Your description makes it seem as if this is established practice and apparently you are not aware of anyone being (negatively) impacted.

@user_ababa_gwzddx ahh I see, so ones ethics end when it gets awkward? This is not a strong argument. This question is also oddly specific to ones situation and ones perception. The general approach to be generous with authorship towards the contributions of graduate and undergraduate students is typically viewed positively. Often times significant effort can go unrewarded because it does not produce a product, but may be very valuable towards understanding something greater, it is up to the PI to decide where this falls. To mitigate this seek out groups with few authors per paper?

@R1NaNo   Thank you very much for your thoughtful response.
Although the PI decides on authorship, there are cases where a student’s contribution is minimal or nonexistent. Often, students are listed as authors without prior notice or clear explanation, leading to feelings of disrespect. This lack of transparency can cause students to question the legitimacy of their authorship, resulting in significant psychological stress and concerns about unintentional involvement in academic misconduct.

@R1NaNo  Switching research groups is a viable option, but it doesn’t change the existing publication record. Since these papers are usually already published, the student has effectively accepted this 'honorary authorship.

@user_ababa_gwzddx yes, but that is for the PI to decide (impact and contribution tot the project) and the student to decline. Unless there is a case of academic misconduct, there should be no impact to the student in the long term.

@R1NaNo  You’re correct that the decision on authorship and contribution largely rests with the project leader (the corresponding author typically knows best about the paper and who deserves authorship).

@R1NaNo  As for students declining authorship, this can be difficult. Often, they only learn they are listed once the paper is submitted or published. Reputable journals rarely allow the removal of authors during review without a valid reason, which could lead to rejection. This can create conflicts between students and advisors.

@R1NaNo  Removing an author’s name after publication also requires a valid reason and a formal correction. If students only discover their authorship after publication, they can’t refuse without potentially revealing a conflict with their advisor.
Overall, aside from the issue of ‘forced authorship,’ these papers typically do not involve other forms of academic misconduct.

If this is a common practice in some places and with some publishers, then there probably isn't a solution as it would require a change in attitude among a large number of people and organizations. Any solution would probably need to be gradual and long term. Publishers, however, could insist on adherence to rules.
However, in much of the world, this would be unethical, and publishers (reputable ones) require permission of all authors to publish. I would question the ethics of any publisher that didn't adhere to this rule.
I'll assume, however, that where it does occur, the professors adding students to publications are motivated by trying to advance those students rather than to hinder them. If such practices are common then the people remaining in those places probably suffer no harm. It does, however, dilute the impact of the people who actually do the work for those publications. Many people (including myself) would consider that unethical. "Authorship", then, is essentially meaningless.
People who have been improperly added to publications might suffer if the work itself is shoddy. And, cutting corners in one area might be correlated with cutting corners in others. They might also suffer if they try to move to a place with higher standards of authorship and it is discovered that they are actually incompetent in fields in which they have "published".

Concerning your third paragraph, there are some fields where significant effort goes into "behind the scenes" work that benefits every result but none individually. A pure direct authorship model also misrepresents the work of many, or just makes larger endeavours impossible from the get go. However, the fields that I know where this is common usually make it clear that there is a collaboration entity involved, not just a bunch of names.
